# Asp.Net Core Web Api With Angular Template Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Type '' is not supported

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I just create a simple project using this template  https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture. i change connection from local DB to actual PostgreSQL database and every thing is working good.

for deployment i done bellow steps

1. I create self signed certificate using PowerShell with bellow command

   *New-SelfSignedCertificate  -Subject "selfsignedcertificate" -DnsName "localhost", " localhost:44341", "giseditor", "gis-co13", "10.1.4.280" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) -FriendlyName "Self-Signed Certificate for .NET Core" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Provider "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" -HashAlgorithm "SHA256"*
2. After that I export this certificate from store to .pfx file and add in project root directory.
3. Now I  configure this file in appsettings.Production.json and also by direct reading this certificate in DependencyInection.cs file in infrastructure project both scenarios give same error in production as given bellow

here is my appsettings.Production.json

```
{
  "UseInMemoryDatabase": false,
  "Provider": "PostgreSQL",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "UseInMemoryDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=GISWebEditorDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
    "DefaultConnection": "User ID =postgres;Password=abc123;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "GeoSpatialWebEditor.WebUI": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      },
      "Key": {
        "Type": "Store",
        "StoreName": "My",
        "StoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
        "Name": "CN=localhost"
      }
      //"Key": {
      //  "Type": "File",
      //  "FilePath": "selfsignedcertificate.pfx",
      //  "Password": "P@$$W0rD!"
      //}
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

this my DependencyInjection.cs Configuration

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseInMemoryDatabase"))
            {
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("UseInMemoryDatabase"));
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));
                */


                // Check Provider and get ConnectionString
                if (configuration["Provider"] == "SQLite")
                {
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlite(
                        configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));
                }
                else if (configuration["Provider"] == "MSSQL")
                {
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));

                }
                else if (configuration["Provider"] == "MySQL")
                {
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                   options.UseMySQL(
                       configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                       b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));
                }
                else if (configuration["Provider"] == "Oracle")
                {
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseOracle(
                        configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));

                }
                else if (configuration["Provider"] == "PostgreSQL")
                {
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                   options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        o => o.UseNetTopologySuite()
                        .MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName))
                   /*.UseLowerCaseNamingConvention()*/);
                }
                // Exception
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid database type");
                }
            }

            services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            //string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "selfsignedcertificate.pfx");
            //var rsaCertificate = new X509Certificate2(path, "P@$$W0rD!", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var rsaCertificate = new X509Certificate2("D:\\testcert\\selfsignedcertificate.pfx", "P@$$W0rD!",  X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var identityBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(rsaCertificate)
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();



            Console.WriteLine("cert private key: " + rsaCertificate.PrivateKey);


            //services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddTransient<IDateTime, DateTimeService>();
            services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();
            services.AddTransient<ICsvFileBuilder, CsvFileBuilder>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            return services;
        }
```

this is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApplication();
            services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration);

            services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddHealthChecks()
                .AddDbContextCheck<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options => 
                options.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilter()));

            services.AddRazorPages();

            // Customise default API behaviour
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
            });

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            services.AddOpenApiDocument(configure =>
            {
                configure.Title = "GeoSpatialWebEditor API";
                configure.AddSecurity("JWT", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Type into the textbox: Bearer {your JWT token}."
                });

                configure.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("JWT"));
            });

            services.AddSingleton<ILog, LogNLog>();
            services.PostConfigure<IdentityServerOptions>(option =>
            {
                //option.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Idp/Logout";
                
            });
           
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseSwaggerUi3(settings =>
            {
                settings.Path = "/api";
                settings.DocumentPath = "/api/specification.json";
            });

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                //spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                string path = Path.Join(env.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp");
                spa.Options.SourcePath = path;


                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

in both situation by adding in appsetting.Production.json or by direct reading in dependencyInjection.cs class in both have same exception in production as given bellow

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Type '' is not supported.

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureClients.GetClients()+MoveNext()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureClients.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()

   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)

   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)

   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.<>c.<AddClients>b__7_1(IServiceProvider sp)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.TestService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type service, ILogger logger, String message, Boolean doThrow)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.Validate(IApplicationBuilder app)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityServer(IApplicationBuilder app, IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions options)

   at GeoSpatialWebEditor.WebUI.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in D:\ProjectsSourceCode\VSProjects\Core\Editor\GeoSpatialWebEditor\src\WebUI\Startup.cs:line 136

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)

   at GeoSpatialWebEditor.WebUI.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\ProjectsSourceCode\VSProjects\Core\Editor\GeoSpatialWebEditor\src\WebUI\Program.cs:line 59

   at GeoSpatialWebEditor.WebUI.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```